# matrix laws and syntax matlab

Tags: matlab, math, matrix

What is happening in my code? I don't understand why I am getting 2 different different matrices when a^-1 * b^-1 = (a*b)^-1 I have tried writing in another language however I keep getting the same inequality.

Input:

```
A = [3 5 2; 2 1 -1; 1 2 2]; 
B = [6 -2 4; 6 4 -12; 12 2 8];

inverseA = A^(-1);
inverseB = B^(-1);

inverseMult = inverseA * inverseB;
inverseMatMult = (A*B)^(-1);

equalityCheck = inverseMult == inverseMatMult;

disp(inverseMult)
disp(inverseMatMult)
disp(equalityCheck)
```

Output:

```
   -0.4038   -0.0863    0.1974
    0.3224    0.0923   -0.1478
   -0.1518   -0.0804    0.0804

   -0.0317    0.0615    0.0694
    0.1190   -0.2619   -0.1667
   -0.0357   -0.0089    0.0625

    0     0     0
    0     0     0
    0     0     0
```

Comment: A note on your `equalityCheck`: You should not use `==` to compare floating point numbers (see [what every programmer should know about floating-point arithmetic](http://floating-point-gui.de/)) but rather check that the difference of the numbers is less than a very small threshold. So rather do `equalityCheck = abs(inverseMult - inverseMatMult) < threshold` where `threshold` is a small number like `1e-10`.

Comment: Note thet multilication is comutative only for numbers (scalars) and scalar multiplication `A.B`. Multiplication of matrices and vector multiplication of vectors `AxB` are **not** comutative.

Comment: *If you put on your socks and shoes, you then take first your shoes then your socks*...

Answer (score 9):

You are assuming an incorrect identity - it should be:

```
(A*B)^-1 = B^-1 * A^-1
```

(See useful list of invertible matrix identities [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix#Other_properties).)

So if you change this line:

```
inverseMatMult = (A*B)^(-1);
```

to:

```
inverseMatMult = (B*A)^(-1);
```

then you should get the expected result. (Note that the equality check may still fail due to rounding errors, but you should see that the two result matrices are identical to a reasonable number of significant figures.)

Answer (score 1):

You may want to recheck the equation.

It might be because (a * b)^-1= (b)^-1 * (a)^-1;

```
           function [t2,t3,t4]= matrixidentity()
           a = [3 5 2; 2 1 -1; 1 2 2];
           b = [6 -2 4; 6 4 -12; 12 2 8];
           t=a^-1;t1=b^-1;
           t2=(a*b)^-1;
           t3=t1*t; 
           t4=t*t1;
           end




           t2 =

                  -0.0317    0.0615    0.0694
                   0.1190   -0.2619   -0.1667
                  -0.0357   -0.0089    0.0625


           t3 =

                  -0.0317    0.0615    0.0694
                   0.1190   -0.2619   -0.1667
                  -0.0357   -0.0089    0.0625


           t4 =

                 -0.4038   -0.0863    0.1974
                  0.3224    0.0923   -0.1478
                 -0.1518   -0.0804    0.0804
```

Here you can see that t2==t3  and thus the equation (a * b)^-1 =(b)^-1 * (a)^-1 holds, whereas

(a * b)^-1=(a)^-1 * (b)^-1 does not hold.

Hope it helps!!